# Как выводить текст, чтобы перенос строк сохранялся?

Tags: javascript, html

Как выводить текст, чтобы перенос строк сохранялся?

Суть проблемы:
есть текст в Базе Данных, он бывает двух форматов - *HTML* (внутри содержит теги) и "*просто текст*"(внутри, как я понимаю, не теги, а `\r`, вероятно). 
С сообщениями в формате *HTML* проблем нет. 
Но если мы выводим сообщения формата "*просто текст*", к примеру:

```
1. Первая сторока
2. Второя сторока
3. Третья строка.
```

То все эти строки получаются слитно:
 1. Первая сторока
    2. Второя сторока
    3. Третья строка.

Проблему можно решить, выводя этот текст командой `alert(mess)` (javascript).
В сообщение `alert` выводится правильно, т.е. с переносом строк.
Подскажите, как сделать чтобы перенос строк сохранялся и при выводе в виде *HTML*?

Comment: так и поменяйте \r на <br> - чем плохо?

Comment: @splash58, напиши с объяснениями сразу в ответ

Comment: Рискну предложить, что если сама информация к базе запрашивается с помощью `php`, то там есть такая функция `nl2br()`. Можно обрабатывать ей те сообщения, что в формате текста.

Comment: Олег Дёгтев, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Есть [цсс-свойство white-space](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/), у него можно указать значение 'pre'. Это как закинуть под тег 'pre', но семантичнее

```
 .myclass {
     white-space: pre;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно закинуть все под тег `<pre></pre>`
А так используй символы переноса строк `\n\r`

Comment: как может помочь использование `\n\r`? К тому же в windows они должны стоять в другом порядке